# Windows Phone 8 Source not available

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8

While debugging I receive this exception:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Visual studio says:
Source information is missing from the debug information of this module.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: `catch(Exception ex){ var thisIsWhatWeNeed = ex.ToString(); }`

Answer (score 1):

> A first chance exception of type

First chance exceptions are usually OK. Its the second one you have to worry about (it means the first chance was not handled).

> Visual studio says: Source information is missing from the debug information of this module.

You might be able to a acquire symbols from Microsoft. See [Use the Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503).

Usually, I set up a project to use Microsoft's symbol server. I then debug my project, and Visual Studio will fetch symbols for libraries from Microsoft.

Fetching from Microsoft takes some time. So after the first fetch, I turn off the feature. This way, you get the symbols that are available without the latency for missing symbols for subsequent debug sessions.

I *don't* know what Microsoft makes available for Windows Phone because I have not done enough development with it. To date, I've only tried porting native libraries through the command line.